# CSS animation to change element height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-animations

I am probably missing something obvious here. I have a basic animation that is triggered on an element hover. It works perfectly. But I want it to add some specific movements too. I tried to just `addClass("")` the style but it did not work. Is this possible?

I know I can just call `$(element).hide();` - but I would like to run the animation just by adding the specific class to the element, if possible.

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/PR9xF/1/

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <li id="hideme"></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
<button id="bt">Click</button>
```

**js**

```
$("#bt").click(function () {
    $("#hideme").removeClass("hide");
    $("#hideme").addClass("hide");
});
```

**css**

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}

li {
    margin-bottom:5px;
    background-color:silver;
    height:120px;
    max-height:120px;
}

#hideme {
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-in;
}

#hideme:hover {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #d5d5d5;
}

.hide {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #d5d5d5;
}
```

Comment: CSS can't transition to a max-height as far as I am aware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare you style like this:

```
#hideme:hover, 
#hideme.hide {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #d5d5d5;
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PR9xF/9/

It's all about rules priorities. When you just define `.hide` alone it has lower weight then `#hideme` so your transition is never applied.

Answer (score 1):

you need to put !important on the hide class. Otherwise it get's overwritten by the id selector.

```
...
.hide {
    max-height: 0 !important;
...
```

http://jsfiddle.net/PR9xF/1/

Also it's probably a good idea to include vendor prefixes to the css if you aren't doing it already.

```
-webkit-transition: all .25s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all .25s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all .25s ease-out;
     -o-transition: all .25s ease-out;
        transition: all .25s ease-out;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css:

```
   .hide {
      display: block;
      transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
      opacity: 0; 
      height: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background: #d5d5d5;
    }
```

Comment: Marcel, this do not work. It hides the element without animating it :/

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?  http://jsfiddle.net/PR9xF/5/

**JS**

```
$("#bt").click(function () {
    $("#hideme").addClass("hide");
});
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style-type:none;
}

li {
    margin-bottom:5px;
    background-color:silver;
    height:120px;
    max-height:120px;
}

.hide {
    max-height: 500px;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-in;
}

.hide:hover {
    max-height: 0;
    transition: max-height 1s ease-out;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #d5d5d5;
}
```